# creating function to convert list of tables into single data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function which can produce a single dataframe from list of dataframes like here t1 is creating a sub tables and i want t_final to produce a single data frames from the list of tables created by t1.

table_list1[[i]] <- t1 is creating if list of tables and these tables should convert into list of tables with one blank row between them

```
df <- mtcars

df1 <- subset(df, vs==1)
df2 <- subset(df, am==1)
df3 <- subset(df, gear==3)

#after this i want to create a list of table produced by t1, and then #create single in final table "t_final" as list of tables    
    # #colnames(t1)[1] <- list1[[d]]
    # df_lst[[i]] <- t1
    # sep_line <- rep("", ncol(df_lst[[i]]))
    # table_list1 <- lapply(df_lst[[i]], function(x)x %>%
    #                         mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~round(.x, 2)),
    #                                across(everything(), ~as.character(.x))) %>%
    #                         rbind(., sep_line))
    # 
    # t2 <- bind_rows(df_lst)
    # rownames(t2) <- NULL
    # t2 <- t2[-nrow(t2), ]
  
  
  }
}
```

Comment: What should the blank row be filled with? NAs?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It's a violation of the way `R` generally tries to store data so you're going to be working against the very language itself.  This feels like a holdover from working in MS Excel. In R it's probably better to just keep it as a `list` of `data.frame`s depending on what you plan to do next.

Comment: Each column of a `data.frame` must have the same data type. Therefore if you want to include `"TT"` with `73` they must all be converted to `character`.

Comment: Blank row should be filled with " ", each coulmn willhave same data type.

Comment: but number of column can be varies but rows will be fixed for all list of tables

Comment: Seems you are mixing datatypes. You will end up having charatcer. ie there will be no numeric columns in your dataframe

Comment: The best practice is to have another column that will distinguish the values of the rows. eg it will be 1 for the first 5 rows, then 2 for the next 5 then 3 and so on

Comment: I agree that lists are probably the object you would need for whatever you are trying to do

Comment: ok, i have not problem with final datatype of final dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many have said in the comments, it is generally a bad practice to structure your data in the way you've shown for a few reasons. It `corrupts` numeric data types into `character`, it mixes information about what is in a column (i.e. the column name) with the data itself. This organization may make sense to a person looking at a spreadsheet, but is not readily intelligible to a computer. Also by storing several tables of data in one with spacer rows this fundamentally misses the point of having tabular data where there is a fixed relationship between everything in one column (it is all information of the same type described by the column name) and everything in each row (unique cases/samples/observations of the variables contained in the columns).

Ok... all that said. It is, of course, possible if ill-advised to do what you're asking. See here for some example code.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# create list of data.frames
l <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  slice_head(n = 3) %>% 
  group_split()

## option 1 - just keep it as a list

## option 2 - merge but retain data types and add ID column
## to indicate which source the data is from
l %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "ID")
#> # A tibble: 9 x 6
#>   ID    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
#>   <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     
#> 1 1              5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa    
#> 2 1              4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa    
#> 3 1              4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa    
#> 4 2              7           3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#> 5 2              6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#> 6 2              6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
#> 7 3              6.3         3.3          6           2.5 virginica 
#> 8 3              5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica 
#> 9 3              7.1         3            5.9         2.1 virginica

## option 3 - hack together one table with space
l %>% 
  map(~mutate(.x, across(everything(), as.character))) %>% 
  map(~rbind(colnames(.x), .x, rep("", ncol(.x)))) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  unname()
#> # A tibble: 15 x 5
#>    ``             ``            ``             ``            ``          
#>    <chr>          <chr>         <chr>          <chr>         <chr>       
#>  1 "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" "Species"   
#>  2 "5.1"          "3.5"         "1.4"          "0.2"         "setosa"    
#>  3 "4.9"          "3"           "1.4"          "0.2"         "setosa"    
#>  4 "4.7"          "3.2"         "1.3"          "0.2"         "setosa"    
#>  5 ""             ""            ""             ""            ""          
#>  6 "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" "Species"   
#>  7 "7"            "3.2"         "4.7"          "1.4"         "versicolor"
#>  8 "6.4"          "3.2"         "4.5"          "1.5"         "versicolor"
#>  9 "6.9"          "3.1"         "4.9"          "1.5"         "versicolor"
#> 10 ""             ""            ""             ""            ""          
#> 11 "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" "Species"   
#> 12 "6.3"          "3.3"         "6"            "2.5"         "virginica" 
#> 13 "5.8"          "2.7"         "5.1"          "1.9"         "virginica" 
#> 14 "7.1"          "3"           "5.9"          "2.1"         "virginica" 
#> 15 ""             ""            ""             ""            ""
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks , but the question is how i can mofdify my function to have the same result